# Xamarin.Forms : Apk size is too large

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I create a new project in Xamarin.Forms and just debug it. I do nothing and just create a Apk file and apk size is 14.2 MB. I found some tutorial regarding and changes Linker behaviour to Link all assemblies. It reduces Apk size to 1 or 2 MB. In fact I am expecting size of such Apk should be in some kbs. What I am missing here?

Comment: Xamarin is packaging it's runtime inside APK to be able actually to run the application. Without the runtime the app can't run on Android. If you plan to deliver your app to most part of users, there is no other way than including MONO runtime inside APK. It is a price for making *crossplatform* applications

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can read all about that here in the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/application_package_sizes/).

Your main problem here is that a lot of .NET stuff is being included as it is not available on your Android device by default.

[image: APK size without Linker (Image by Xamarin)]

> 15.8 MB is a larger download size than we’d like. The problem is the BCL libraries, as they include mscorlib, System, and Mono.Android,
>   which provide a lot of the necessary components to run your
>   application. However, they also provide functionality that you may not
>   be using in your application, so it may be preferable to exclude these
>   components.

But they may not be necessary! This is where the Linker comes in.

[image: APK size when using the Linker (Image by Xamarin)]

> When we build an application for distribution, we execute a process,
>   known as Linking, that examines the application and removes any code
>   that is not directly used. This process is similar to the
>   functionality that Garbage Collection provides for heap-allocated
>   memory.

You can access the linker settings from your Xamarin.Droid project properties. Look around at the different settings there and play with them to see what it has for effect.

Comment: Thanks for immediate response. I followed - Double click on android project->Android Build ->Linker ->Link All Assemblies. Is it ok or something else?

Comment: I chose linker behaviour  **Link SDK assemblies only**

Comment: when i use linker i get the following error **The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly**

Comment: Examine the rest of the output. There is probably a reason for it.

Comment: I don't get below 16 MB apk size with linking and proguard and on Android itself it doesn't go below 30 MB : (